# how to get city name from IP address

Tags: ip-geolocation

Hi I have a list of IP addresses of my user registrations, can anybody suggest best ip2location free services (REST services are preferrable for me)...

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use this site 
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

for example
http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=20b96dca8b9a5d37b0355e9461c66e76eed30a2274422fa6213d9de6ffb2b34e&ip=74.125.45.100

instead of this ip=74.125.45.100 you can put other and it gives you what you want

I hope this help you

Comment: This API is very very slow use `http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=76.109.14.196` instead

Comment: but accuracy of geoplugin is like 400 miles.