# In Android and Ios, how to get city name with or without using GPS?

Tags: android, ios

How to get city name with out using GPS ,GPRS or WiFi? In case we have to use GPS how to identify city name?

Comment: You want to locate the device without using GPS? On iOS MapKit provides. Reverse geocoder API but you'll need to know the device's position...

Answer (score 1):

First get your last known location and get the latlag

than pass that in google api url [Google Web Api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lat,lag&sensor=true)

It will give you json response and you can get what ever you want area, city, state, country etc.

Answer (score 0):

[One way might be that you can get a city name via IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815825/how-to-get-city-name-from-ip-address).

It's not foolproof, though. [I just tried the API at this website](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php), but it listed me in San Jose when I'm actually physically in San Francisco.

Answer (score 0):

You want a reverse geocoder for this purpose, such as the one [built-in to Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse). An example of HTML and Javascript usage of this follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onclick="codeLatLng()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is interpreted to generate [this page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/geocoding-reverse). Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

generally GPS for outside and wi-fi for inside is used to get location then get city name from it, in your case IP address seems to be solution but actually it might be wrong